# classpath issue happening on my android studio

Tags: java, kotlin, classpath

I have installed the android studio but it is not working welly. it shows a classpath not identified issue and I cannot work on it. I have install and uninstall it several times but still it is not working. My laptop is old but 8gb ram. I have to work on this laptop.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your `.gradle` files? Also: Please don't share any images here, copy it and use three \` tags before and after your code/error message (without the backslash.)

Comment: hello, you there?

Comment: sir, I don'r understand. How would share my gradle file unless i took any screenshot. please sir

Comment: till three I am trying but didnt found any result. I am learning from free videos o you tbe but still didn't found solution

Comment: here is the gradle file

Comment: https://ibb.co/3p1wxLr

Comment: Can you provide your entire build.gradle files ? There should be two: one App and one Module, can you add the code from them in your question ?

Comment: Step by step tutorial on how to share a file in StackOverflow: 1. Navigate to `build.gradle`. 2. Copy the dependency part & the repositories part. 3. Edit this post and paste both parts of the file content in your question surrounded by ````

Comment: thank you so much sir. i think m problem solved but still not sure. But i hope. sir, can you suggest  e any good you tube channel tht would be helpful for me to learn.